# Flutter - When textformfield gets focus it resets my form state and causes the form to rebuild

Tags: flutter

I have a form with a few custom segment widgets and a few FormTextFields.  The Segment widgets change the state in my form and that part works.  For example the first Segment set the value of _selectedBetType.

The problem is when one of the TextFormFields receives focus, _selectedBetType gets set back to 0 and the Form rebuilds.

Here is my Form.

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
    import 'package:pari/game.dart';
    import 'package:pari/widgets/segment_widget.dart';


    class WatchedGameForm extends StatefulWidget {
      Game _game;

      BetType _selectedBetType = BetType.Moneyline;
      int _selectedTeamIndex = 0;
      int _selectedOverUnderIndex = 0;

      WatchedGameForm(this._game);

      @override
      State createState() => _WatchedGameFormState();
    }

    class _WatchedGameFormState extends State {
      final _formKey = GlobalKey();

      _WatchedGameFormState();

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        print(widget._selectedBetType);
        return Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              _buildBetTypeSegmentWidget(),
              _buildTeamSegmentWidget(),
              _buildOverUnderSegmentWidget(),
              _buildPointsField(),
              _buildOddsField(),
            ],
          )
        );
      }

      Widget _buildBetTypeSegmentWidget() {
        return SegmentWidget(
          selectedValue: widget._selectedBetType.index,
          items: [
            SegmentItem(BetType.Moneyline.index, describeEnum(BetType.Moneyline)),
            SegmentItem(BetType.Spread.index, describeEnum(BetType.Spread)),
            SegmentItem(BetType.TotalPoints.index, describeEnum(BetType.TotalPoints)),
          ],
          onValueChanged: (int value)  {
            setState(() {
              widget._selectedBetType = BetType.values[value];
            });
          },
        );
      }

      Widget _buildTeamSegmentWidget() {
        if (widget._selectedBetType == BetType.TotalPoints)
          return Container();

        return SegmentWidget(
          selectedValue: widget._selectedTeamIndex,
          items: [
            SegmentItem(0, widget._game.awayTeam),
            SegmentItem(1, widget._game.homeTeam),
          ],
          onValueChanged: (int value)  {
            setState(() {
              widget._selectedTeamIndex = value;
            });
          },
        );
      }

      Widget _buildOverUnderSegmentWidget() {
        if (widget._selectedBetType != BetType.TotalPoints)
          return Container();

        return SegmentWidget(
          selectedValue: widget._selectedOverUnderIndex,
          items: [
            SegmentItem(0, "Over"),
            SegmentItem(1, "Under"),
          ],
          onValueChanged: (int value)  {
            setState(() {
              widget._selectedOverUnderIndex = value;
            });
          },
        );
      }

      Widget _buildPointsField() {
        if (widget._selectedBetType == BetType.Moneyline)
          return Container();

        return Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: TextFormField(
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            textAlign: TextAlign.end,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: (widget._selectedBetType == BetType.Spread) ? 'Point Spread' : 'Total Points',
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
            )
          ),
        );
      }

      Widget _buildOddsField() {
        return Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: TextFormField(
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              textAlign: TextAlign.end,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Odds',
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              )
          ),
        );
      }

    }
```

Comment: save values in `TextFormField` using onChanged(), onSave() or using a TextEditingController

Comment: Thanks, but that's completely not the problem.

Comment: Your stateful variables should be inside the `State`. Widget members should be final.

Comment: @JacobPhillips Thanks for the suggestion.  Any idea though about the problem I am having?

Comment: That might fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have variables outside the state.
You can move,

```
BetType _selectedBetType = BetType.Moneyline;
```

inside

```
class _WatchedGameFormState extends State 
{
 ...
}
```